# Ranking in class + Resume

Tags: cv, ranking

I have a question about how to write my ranking in a class in my CV. I mean, after graduation from the university for my BSc degree, my ranking due to overall GPA among the class of 30 students was 2. The class and the students in which we started our BSc degree education and graduated after 8 or 9 semesters. I want to high light this ranking in my CV in the section of honors and awards. How should I mention this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is usually done in the section where you list your degree:

2008-2012 University of Big City - BSc (Hons.) Difficult Subject (Class rank: 2 of 30)

or similar.

Comment: Can I also categorize this honor as honors 2nd, honors 2i or something like this? I am not familiar with such categorizations or literature of the honor.

Comment: No. The descriptions 2i, Upper Second, and the like are titles that *may* be used by a university to differentiate between their graduates (so five people might get a 'first', the next 10 an upper second,  etc). Given that you're asking this question, I suspect yours doesn't use this.

Comment: No, the university doesn't grant it's graduates such descriptions. However, they have certified me that I am ranked second among the graduated people in the same class. And I think I should exactly mention such thing in the Honors section of my CV.

Comment: Indeed. I'm just saying that you shouldn't describe it as "honours second", or whatever, as that is likely to mislead people (and underrepresent your achievement).

Comment: Exactly. The best way of putting such honor in my CV seems to Copy/Translate word by word of what they have certified me. Not to add more or less; and not to use unfamiliar words and expressions.

Comment: It depends who's going to read it. *I* certainly wouldn't know what "honors the second" meant. I wouldn't interpret it as meaning you were ranked 2 of 30 in the class. If your readership is likely to be familiar with the phrase, translation may be ok.

Comment: As you said, it is more safe not to change the phrases and to use the most exact words. Thanks, You helped me so much Avid.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to avid's answer; you may write a **Degrees and Awards** section:

**Degrees and Awards**
2009 September, ABC Corp. Project Competition, "Saving the Earth from Pollution", *1st place*
2010 March, Very Good Conference, "Research About Humanity", *Best paper award*
2010-2011, fall semester, University of the Worls, GPA: 4.00/4.00, *Outstanding student*
2012 June, High honor student, graduated with GPA: 3.97/4.00, Degree: 2 of 30

etc.

One more thing, you should put *only* the highlights of your educational life. If you don't want to highlight something, don't write it in your CV.

Comment: Is this section different from the "Honors and Awards"? Because I have seen some CVs that mention the phrase "honors the 2nd" in the education section of their CV. How should the literature of such honor be like?

Comment: No, this is the same section. Title might be different. I prefer the word *degree*, you might prefer *honor*. I think nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

GPA: ...
Ranked 1st ... (if you want to include details, include only the class. I do not recommend to include the number of studends, if there are 50 or 350 students, it does not matter.)
It's short and descriptive as it needs to be.